# How translate "MD5 checksum"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

En una aplicación estan las las siguientes listas:

- Size:
- Modified:
- Contents:
- **Points to:**
- **MD5 checksum:**

Yo trascribí las tres primeras pero las dos últimas no sé a que pueden hacer referencia.

¿Alguna idea?

---

Hasta ahora tengo:

- Tamaño:
- Fecha de modificación:
- Contenidos:
- **Apunta a:**
- **Comprobación MD5:**

¿Son correctas?

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct would be the following

> **Tamaño:**
>
> **Fecha de modificación:**
>
> **Contenido:**
>
> **Apunta a:**
>
> **Comprobación MD5:**

Comprobación means verification. And that's how you say it in this context.

Answer (score 3):

*Suma MD5* se usa también. Ver por ejemplo el [artículo sobre MD5 de Wikipedia en español](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

El Diccionario Oxford propone por *checksum* las traducciones *suma de comprobación*, *suma de verificación*, o *suma de control*.

Comment: You're right. The addition is the first process for this algorithm. But I prefer use Comprobación, because what the algorithm do is check (comprobar) that the sum (suma) was successful or not.

Comment: @Lucio, bueno, es cuestión de perspectiva si se considera que la comprobación es parte del algoritmo o no. Desde mi punto de vista el MD5 es una transformación que genera un *hash* y ese *hash* es lo que pondrás después de los dos puntos; la comprobación se hace (o no, siendo lo que son los usuarios) después.

Answer (score 2):

**Points to** significa en español

> apunta a

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE!